# How to compare two files to create a third file with the all possible pair of values correspond to one row of first file?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have two files. The first file File_A.txt with n number of columns is like this:

```
SRK_00017   MRS10904.1
SRK_00017   MRS14430.1
SRK_00005   MRS13611.1
...
```

The second file File_B.txt looks like:

```
MRS10904.1  DMN02113.10
MRS10983.1  DMN07690.11
SRK_00011   DMN02311.14
MRS13611.1  DMN12833.2
MRS10981.1  DMN00149.23
SRK_00011   DMN02872.13
MRS14430.1  DMN12777.2
SRK_00005   DMN00659.13
SRK_04765   DMN12781.2
SRK_04765   DMN03028.10
MRS13611.1  DMN1234.10
SRK_00017   DMN03028.10
SRK_00017   DMN03029.10
SRK_14211   DMN13843.1
SRK_00017   DMN00069.20
MRS10904.1  DMN00659.13
....
```

I want to create a new third file File_C.txt like:

```
SRK_00017       DMN03028.10     DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017       DMN03029.10     DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017       DMN00069.20     DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017       DMN03028.10     DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017       DMN03029.10     DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017       DMN00069.20     DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017       DMN03028.10     DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017       DMN03028.10     DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017       DMN00069.20     DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00005       DMN00659.13     DMN12833.2  MRS13611.1
SRK_00005       DMN00659.13     DMN1234.10  MRS13611.1
....
```

The second file contains the values (as DMN..) of the IDs SRK_ and MRS. All the SRK_ are in coulmn1 of File_A and all the MRS are in coulmn2 of File_A. Any of the SRK_ and MRS may have multiple DMN values (given in File_B). What I actually want in my File_C is all the possible pairing of the values of SRK_ and MRS belongs to one row of File_A. For example the first row in File_A is SRK_00017  MRS10904.1 and if we will look at File_B SRK_00017 has three DMN values (DMN03028.10, DMN03029.10, DMN00069.20) and the MRS10904.1 also has two DMN values (DMN02113.10 and DMN00659.13). So for the first row of File_A there will have 3*2 = 6 possible pairs of DMN. There are in the first six lines of resultant File_C.txt. I hope I am able to convey my question.

Comment: In your expected output: Why is `DMN02113.10` occuring in column 3 in the six top rows? Shouldn't there be some `DMN00659.13` there?

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;b[$1 FS a[$1]]=$2;next}
{for (i=1;i<=a[$2];i++)
      for (j=1;j<=a[$1];j++)
         print $1,b[$1 FS j],b[$2 FS i],$2
}' File_B.txt File_A.txt

SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN12833.2 MRS13611.1
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN1234.10 MRS13611.1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Gnu Awk version 4.1 you can use arrays of arrays like

```
gawk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$1][$2]++
    next
}
{
    for (i in a[$1])
        for (j in a[$2])
            print $1, i, j, $2
}' File_B.txt File_A.txt
```

Output:

```
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN12833.2 MRS13611.1
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN1234.10 MRS13611.1
```

Comment: Looks easlier with `arrays of arrays`, but the only problem is, can't control the display order. Second, the `++` is useless

Comment: @BMW Yes, but is the order important?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl version.

Note: I have left out any error checking for the sake of clarity (not sure what the policy is on that here).

```
open my $file_a, '<', 'File_A.txt';
open my $file_b, '<', 'File_B.txt';
open my $file_c, '>', 'File_C.txt';
my %map;
foreach (<$file_b>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id,$dmn) = split;
    push(@{ $map{$id} },$dmn);
}
foreach (<$file_a>) {
    chomp;
    my ($srk,$mrs) = split;
    for my $dmn2 ( @{ $map{$mrs} } ) {
        for my $dmn1 ( @{ $map{$srk} } ) {
            print $file_c "$srk $dmn1 $dmn2 $mrs\n";
        }
    }
}
close $file_a;
close $file_b;
close $file_c;
```

File_C.txt contains:

```
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN12833.2 MRS13611.1
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN1234.10 MRS13611.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shell-script version, using `sort` and `join`.  This works for me on [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) 12.04 and [osx](/questions/tagged/osx):

```
#!/bin/bash

sort $2 > $2.MRS.SRK

sort $1 > $1.SRK
join $1.SRK $2.MRS.SRK | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \+/\1:/' | sort > SRK.join

sort -k2 $1 > $1.MRS
join -o "1.1 1.2 2.2" -1 2 $1.MRS $2.MRS.SRK | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \+/\1:/' | sort > MRS.join

join SRK.join MRS.join | sed 's/\([^ ]*\):\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]* [^ ]*\)/\1 \3 \2/'
```

Output is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./DMN.sh File_A.txt File_B.txt 
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN1234.10 MRS13611.1
SRK_00005 DMN00659.13 DMN12833.2 MRS13611.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN00659.13 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN02113.10 MRS10904.1
SRK_00017 DMN00069.20 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN03028.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
SRK_00017 DMN03029.10 DMN12777.2 MRS14430.1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Ignoring sorts, the basic flow is:

1. `join` on field 1 of both files (the "SRK" field).  Ensure field output order is "SRK MRS DMN"
2. `sed` a colon in between "SRK" and "MRS" fields in resulting output, so these two fields appear as one field to future `join`s
3. `join` on field 2 of FileA and field 1 of FileB (the "MRS" field).  Ensure field output order is "SRK MRS DMN"
4. `sed` a colon in between "SRK" and "MRS" fields in resulting output, so these two fields appear as one field to future `join`s
5. `join` results of 2. and 4. above on the "SRK:MRS" field
6. `sed` to remove the colon and move the resulting output fields into the order "SRK DMN DMN MRS"

Note input to `join` must be sorted on the join field, so sorts are effectively required before each `join` here.  So no guarantees on the sort order of the final output.  But I think that would normally be the case for any kind of DB join.

---

This can also be rewritten all as one (long) command, without the intermediate files, and using bash primitives instead of `sed`:

```
join <(
  join <(
    sort File_A.txt) <(
    sort File_B.txt) |
  while read a b; do echo "$a:$b"; done | sort) <(
  join -o "1.1 1.2 2.2" -1 2 <(
    sort -k2 File_A.txt) <(
    sort File_B.txt) |
  while read a b; do echo "$a:$b"; done | sort) |
while IFS=" :" read a b c d; do echo "$a $c $d $b"; done > File_C.txt
```

Note `join` can read only one of its input files from stdin, so `<()` process substitution is used extensively to pipe input to `join`.

Note also both input files must effectively be read twice.